Acer Nitro AP18E8M battery stops charging at 67 % under Windows 11
I have replaced the dead battery of a two years old dead Acer Nitro AP18E8M. For calibration I discharged it to 0 V and charged it again. But it stopped at 67 % charge and an orange light started blinking. I am running Windows 11.
As far as I know no charging limit is set in power options of Windows 11. Is it a adapter problem or battery problem?

It cannot be a charger problem, since then it woudn't have charge the laptop at all. It might be a problem with the battery, if it's old, but I'd suggest trying to find other software-based solution before replacing any hardware part

@MuditKapil hi! are there any news?

Your problem description is not precise. You do not state if you replaced the dead battery by a new or a used one. You did neither state the capacity of the old Acer battery and the capacity of the replaced battery. Furthermore you should mention what type/model of mains adapter you are using.

The most probable case is that your battery informed your notebook about an unexpected charge interruption which triggered the orange flashing light.
There are two explanations. They might apply simultaneously.

The replaced battery is full
Your battery contains a circuit that is called "BMS" (battery management system). This system protects your battery which typically contains a bunch of 18650 rechargeable LiIo-batteries against unwanted states such as overvoltage, undervoltage and excessive currents.
Some of those LiIo-batteries are wired in series and in parallel.
If the voltage of one group of parallel wired cells exceeds the allowed maximum voltage during the charging process, for instance 4.15 Volt, the BMS closes the charge line.
There is always one group that interrupts the charging process that way.
It does not matter, though, as long as the capacity of each group is close to another because all groups will be equally full charged.
Aging and cycles will cause an asymmetrical capacity downfall. The weakest group triggers a stop of charging and a forced battery shutdown during discharging.

Your notebook was unable to read out the new (lower) capacity
Your notebook is measuring against the capacity of the old powerful battery.



There is a setting in many laptops, to stop the battery from charging over a specific precent, so these last percentage will have longer lifespan, and the battery will hold at medium-performance for a longer time.
On a Lenovo, you can disable it from Lenovo Vantage.
It'd seem there's a similar setting for Acer, with an app
named "AcerCareCenter". If you don't already have that, try to type the serial-number of your computer in this site (not in the search-field in the top, but in a field lower within the page). You can probably find the serial-number on the bottom of the laptop.

In Ubuntu also it is not getting charged up and stuck to 67% so it's not about Acer care centre

@MuditKapil So, is it a setting from the BIOS/UEFI? It is absolutely not the charger, and might be the battery but doesn't seem so.

Have you tried to power-cycle the device using the power-interrupt button? https://us.v-cdn.net/6029997/uploads/editor/tw/rs5jejwdbp20.png ( Black box, not white circle )
